# Why the surface of the superconducting wire carrying current $I\ll I_C$ is where current mainly flow through instead of interior layer?

Tags: superconductivity

I am considering about a superconducting cylindrical wire carrying current $I\ll I_C$ ($I_C$ is the critical current). And based on 2nd London equation and Maxwell equation I arrived at the Laplacian equation:

$\nabla^2j_s(r)=\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}\,j_s(r)$

where $j_s$ is the supercurrent that the wire is carrying, $\lambda$ is the penetration depth, and $r=0$ is the core of the wire. The original vector Laplacian equation has been degraded in to scalar Laplacian equation by applying the symmetry.

And correspondingly the solution to the equation above is

$j_s(r)=A\,e^{-r/\lambda}+B\,e^{r/\lambda}$

What troubles me is the boundary condition: it seems clear that current should only exist in the width of $\lambda$. Why it can't be the core but the outer surface? Is there something I missed here?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but your solution for j$_s$(r) is wrong. You seem to operate in cylindrical coordinates, but tried to solve for r as it it were a Cartesian coordinates. In other words, you tried to solve j''(r) = j(r), but this is not the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates. If you write your equation in cylindrical coordinates, you should get Bessel functions in your answer. You can look up Helmholtz equation in cylindrial coordinates if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the solution is not wrong since r here is not a vector but a scalar after I use the translational invariace to single out the dependence on $\theta$ and $\phi$ in $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to use the correct expression for the Laplacian. If you use the Cartesian expression, your conductor is no longer cylindrical. See for example http://www.physics.usu.edu/riffe/3750/Lecture%2020.pdf.